# Cloud-Custodian resource:ec2 send mail region and account-name variable problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, cloudcustodian

I have prepared a Cloud-CustodianPolicy which detects new created EC2s and send emails. The structure works but I could not write account-name and region information into nor subject or body of mail. While yaml can understand in role part as {account_id}, it can not understand inside of mail related part. Is there a way to use these parametric variables inside policy?

yaml file;

```
 ...
  role: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/administrator", 
 ...

  actions:
      - type: notify
        template: default
        priority_header: '2'
        subject: "Huge Sized Type EC2 has been PoweredON accountID:{account_id} {account_name}-{region}"
```

mail subject in the mail sent;

> subject: Huge Sized Type EC2 has been PoweredON accountID:{account_id}
>   {account_name}-{region}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed problem by adding double curly braces and used `account`. The format below has worked in my config for the `subject`.

```
subject: Huge Sized Type EC2 has been PoweredON in {{account}} on {{region}}
```